# use multiple LEFT JOINs from multiple datasets SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join, union

I need to perform multiple JOINs, I am grabbing the data from multiple tables and JOINing on id. The tricky part is that one table I need to join twice. Here is the code:

```
(
    SELECT
        content.brand_identifier AS brand_name,
        CAST(timestamp(furniture.date) AS DATE) AS order_date,
total_hearst_commission
    FROM
        `furniture_table` AS furniture
        LEFT JOIN `content_table` AS content ON furniture.site_content_id = content.site_content_id
    WHERE
        (
            timestamp(furniture.date) >= TIMESTAMP('2020-06-01 00:00:00')
        )
)
UNION
(
    SELECT
        flowers.a_merchant_name AS merchant_name
    FROM
        `flowers_table` AS flowers
        LEFT JOIN `content` AS content ON flowers.site_content_id = content.site_content_id
)
GROUP BY
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
ORDER BY
    4 DESC
LIMIT
    500
```

I thought I could use UNION but it gives me an error `Syntax error: Expected keyword ALL or keyword DISTINCT but got "("`

Comment: This query has multiple errors. As a starter, both subqeries do not return the same number of columns. Sample data and desired results would help clarifying what you want.

Comment: SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... I.e. skip those parentheses.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: this is the minimal reproducible example. I don't know how else to minimize it. The entire code is what I need to solve, that is why I posted it here.

Comment: While the syntax is not correct, what is the intended purpose of the `group by`? It makes no sense to group by all the columns. And the first result only has three column anyway (fewer than 4).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment, but like GHB states, the queries do not have the same number of columns; therefore, UNION will not work here.

I think it would be helpful to know why sub-queries are needed in the first place. I'm guessing this query does not product the results you want, so please elaborate on why that is.

```
    select 
        f.a_merchant_name as merchant_name,
        c.brand_identifier as brand_name, 
        CAST(timestamp(f.date) AS DATE) AS order_date,
        total_hearst_commission
    from furniture_table f
    left join content_table c on c.site_content_id = f.site_content_id
    where timestamp(f.date) >= TIMESTAMP('2020-06-01 00:00:00')
    group by 1,2,3,4
```